# Jenkins - Prevent configuration from running parallel

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm using Jenkins for my CI automated tests.

I'm testing my Chrome plugin using Jenkins.
I have 2 virtual machines, each for browser (Chrome for Windows, Chrome for Mac).

I test my plugin against the 3 most recent version of chrome.
So my matrix looks like the following:
Chrome for Mac: ver 58, ver 57, ver 56 
Chrome for Windows: ver 58, ver 57, ver 56

My problem is that when I trigger my job, all 3 versions of Mac begin to run parallel and all 3 versions of Windows begin to run parallel.

I need my execution sequence to look like this:
1. Chrome Mac ver 56 - Chrome Windows ver 56
2. Chrome Mac ver 57 - Chrome Windows ver 57 
3. Chrome Mac ver 58 - Chrome Windows ver 58

So that at any given moment single version of chrome for Mac will be executed and a single version of chrome for Windows will be executed.

I would glad for help :)

Thanks!